# Discrete mathematics generating function grabbing balloons restricted.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Say we have 3 different kind of balloons: blue, red and black. If we want to grab k balloons with the restriction that the number of red balloons is al least twice the number of blue balloons. How can i represent this in a generating function? The order does not matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporarily introduce three variables, $x,y$, and $z$; we’ll use the exponent on $x$ to represent the number of black balloons, the exponent on $y$ to represent the number of blue balloons **plus** the minimum number of red balloons required to accompany them, and the exponent on $z$ to represent the number of red balloons over and above that minimum. The exponent on $y$ is necessarily a multiple of $3$, since each blue balloon must be accompanied by a minimum of $2$ red balloons. A term $x^py^{3q}z^r$ then represents a selection of $p$ black balloons, $q$ blue balloons, and $2q+r$ red balloons; the total number of balloons represented is $p+3q+r$, the sum of the exponents.

Thus, the terms of the product

$$\left(\sum_{p\ge 0}x^p\right)\left(\sum_{q\ge 0}y^{3q}\right)\left(\sum_{r\ge 0}z^r\right)\tag{1}$$

represent the possible selections of balloons, and we’re interested in the number of terms $x^py^{3q}z^r$ for which $p+3q+r=k$. If we replace $y$ and $z$ by $x$ in $(1)$, ghat’s just the coefficient of $x^k$, so the desired generating function is

$$\left(\sum_{p\ge 0}x^p\right)\left(\sum_{q\ge 0}x^{3q}\right)\left(\sum_{r\ge 0}x^r\right)\;;\tag{2}$$

I’ll leave to you the pretty straightforward task of finding a closed form for $(2)$.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Very clear explanation!

Comment: @discreteballoons: You're welcome -- and thank you!

Comment: @BrianM. Scott Can you help us further on to give some help with the exp. gen. function when we grab exactly 3 red balloons and more blue than black balloons? Thanx in advance!

Comment: @iJup: There are always $3$ red balloons. If there are $p$ black balloons, there are certainly $p$ blue balloons as well; that accounts for $2p$ balloons. Finally, there are $q$ additional blue balloons for some $q\ge 1$. Thus, we want the coefficient of $x^n$ in $$x^3\left(\sum_{p\ge 0}x^p\right)\left(\sum_{q\ge 1}x^q\right)\;.$$

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! In response to the above expression and (2) (with the summations): what sort of closed form we are looking for to express the generating function?

Comment: @iJup: Oops: that should have been $$x^3\left(\sum_{p\ge 0}x^{2p}\right)\left(\sum_{q\ge 1}x^q\right)\;.$$ The first summation is just a geometric series with ratio $x^2$, so it’s equal to $\frac1{1-x^2}$. The second is a geometric series with ratio $x$ and first term $x$, so ...

Comment: And does it make a difference if order counts for grabbing three balloons, $p$ black, and $\geq p$ blue balloons?

Comment: @iJup: If the number of blue balloons is allowed to be equal to the number of black balloons, then the second summation must start at $q=0$: you’re now allowing the excess to be $0$.

Comment: Sorry for another comment. If order counts, we are interested in case summations in thus form $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^k$?